# Passing escaped url as controller parameter in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, escaping

The controller `Home` has a method `export`:

```
public function export($id , $url){
     ...
}
```

In my smarty template, there is a link : `<a href="/home/export/{%$id%}/{%$url%}">export</a>`.
If url is http://www.facebook.com, `export` method just get **http:** as the value of url. So i change it to `<a href="/home/export/{%$id%}/{%$url|escape:'url'%}">export</a>`, to escape slashes in url.

Then the location becomes "**.../home/export/59/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F** "(is what i want), but with **"404 Not Found"** Error(is not what i want).

Why is that? Shouldn't the location maps to `export` method? And how to map to it with full url?

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter controllers, each method argument comes from the URL separated by a `/` slash. For this kind of work Codeigniter's through an error like "The URI contains disallowed chatacters" error.
I'd suggest you use query strings for this task to avoid all these problems:

http://example.com/export/?id=1&url=http://www.facebook.com

```
public function export()
{
    $link = $this->input->get('url');
    echo $link;
}
```

In Codeigniter you can get full url :

```
$this->uri->uri_string()


public function export($id , $url){
     echo  $this->uri->uri_string();
}
```